# any clue how to solve this lim

Tags: calculus

Having trouble starting to solve this limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^{3n+1}
$$

I understand it's related to $e$ some how, but having hard time getting there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to recall that when $u_n \to +\infty$
$$
\lim\left(1+\frac{1}{u_n}\right)^{u_n} = e.
$$

In this case,

$$
\lim \left(1+\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\right)^{3n+1} = \lim \left(\underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}}\right)^{\frac{n^2+1}{n+1}}}_{\to e}\right)^{\frac{(3n+1)(n+1)}{n^2+1}}=e^{\lim \frac{(3n+1)(n+1)}{n^2+1}} = e^3
$$

Answer (score 0):

REcall that if $a_n\to0$ then $(1+a_n)^{1/a_n}\to e$.

So, let's call $a_n:=\frac{n+1}{n^2+1}\to0$ and $b_n:=3n+1$. So your limit is $$L=\lim(1+a_n)^{b_n}=\lim \left[(1+a_n)^{1/a_n}\right]^{a_n b_n}.$$
So If you can calculate $l:=\lim a_nb_n$, then $L=e^l$.

---

In your case, you only need to calculate $\lim \frac{(n+1)(3n+1)}{n^2+1}$.